# Using jQuery in CKFinder dialog

Tags: jquery, jcrop, ckfinder

Does any way to use jQuery and jQuery plugins inside CKFinder 2 dialogs exist? I just want to use Jcrop to crop images with my plugin.
For example code below doesn't work. `jQuery(document).ready(...)` event fires well, but inside it I just unable to select any element of my dialog. So, is it possible at all?

```
CKFinder.dialog.add("ImageCroppingDialog", function (api) {
return {
    title: "Test",
    minWidth: 480,
    minHeight: 750,
    onShow: function () {
        var file = api.getSelectedFile();
        var url = file.getUrl();
        var doc = this.getElement().getDocument();
        var img = doc.getById('cropbox');
        img.setAttribute('src', url);
        jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            jQuery('#cropbox').Jcrop();
        });
    },
    contents: [
            {
                id: 'tab1',
                label: '',
                title: '',
                expand: true,
                padding: 0,
                elements: [
                        {
                            type: 'html',
                            html: '<h3>Select area to crop.</h3><img id="cropbox" src="" style="max-width: 480px; max-height: 580px;"></img>'
                                    + '<script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>'
                                    + '<script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/crop/jquery.jcrop.min.js"></script>'
                        }
                ]
            }
        ],
    buttons: [CKFinder.dialog.cancelButton, CKFinder.dialog.okButton]
};
});

CKFinder.addPlugin('ImageCropper', function (api) {

api.addFileContextMenuOption({ label: 'Crop image', command: "ImageCropper" }, function (api, file) {
    api.openDialog("ImageCroppingDialog");
    if (!file.isImage()) {
        api.openMsgDialog("Image cropping", "This feature is only available for editing images.");
        return;
    } //end check if isImage()
});

});
```

Answer (score 3):

I noticed that CKFinder is using an iFrame, confusing the jquery selector.

You should try it like this

```
$("#cropbox", $("iframe:first").contents());
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a [plugin version](http://ckeditor.com/blog/CKEditor_for_jQuery) of ckEditor which has jQuery integration. If you cannot switch to that version, there are [several ways](http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries) of passing the jQuery object into the CKFinder object, the simplest of which would be:

```
CKFinder.prototype.J = jQuery;
```